# Python 3- assigns grades

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, program-entry-point

•   Define a function to prompt the user to enter valid scores until they enter a sentinel value -999.  Have this function both create and return a list of these scores. Do not store -999 in the list!
•   Have main( ) then pass this  the list to a second function which traverses the list of scores printing them along with their appropriate grade.

I am having trouble with the getGrade function, it gives the error for i in grades: name 'grades' is not defined.

```
def main():
   grade = getScore()
   print(getGrade(grade))

def getScore():
   grades = []
   score = int(input("Enter grades (-999 ends): "))
   while score != -999:
      grades.append(score)
      score = int(input("Enter grades (-999 ends): "))
   return grades

def getGrade(score):
   best = 100
   for i in grades:
      if score >= best - 10:
         print(" is an A")
      elif score >=  best - 20:
         print(score, " is a B")
      elif score >= best - 30:
         print(score, " is a C")
      elif score >= best - 40:
         print(score, " is a D")
      else:
         print(score, "is a F")

main()
```

Comment: Your function is named `getScore`, not `getScores`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You defined your function to be `getScore()` but you're calling `getScores()`, so as would be expected this throws an error because the function you're calling doesn't actually exist / hasn't been defined.

***Addendum***: Since you changed your question, after fixing the previous error.

Likewise you're calling `grades`, but `grades` is defined in your other function *not* within the scope of the function where you're trying to iterate over `grades`.